Cannot read properties of undefined on Ziggy Route name
When running php artisan inertia:start-ssr, I encounter the following error in the console during page load, although sounds.categories is correctly defined and the project works properly except in the SSR part:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sounds.categories')
    at new N (file:///F:/Projects/laravel.site.ir/bootstrap/ssr/ssr.js:2102:25)
    at Proxy.T (file:///F:/Projects/laravel.site.ir/bootstrap/ssr/ssr.js:2203:14)
    at _sfc_ssrRender (file:///F:/Projects/laravel.site.ir/bootstrap/ssr/assets/Index-d177b86d.js:119:21)
    at renderComponentSubTree (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:695:9)
    at renderComponentVNode (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:641:12)
    at renderVNode (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:755:14)
    at renderComponentSubTree (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:710:7)
    at renderComponentVNode (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:641:12)
    at renderVNode (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:755:14)
    at renderComponentSubTree (F:\Projects\laravel.site.ir\node_modules\@vue\server-renderer\dist\server-renderer.cjs.js:710:7)

route plugin: ziggy-js
How can I resolve this issue?

So where do you have sounds.categories? Any async operation there?

I have the same problem using tightenco/ziggy: 2.1.0, but in a older project with tightenco/ziggy: 1.8.2is not happening. What version have you installed?

I think I have the solution. This happens because inside the setup() method the route() function is not declared yet. So if you do this:
<script>
import {defineComponent, h} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: "MyComponent",
    setup () {
        const myRoute = route('sounds.categories')
        return { myRoute }
    },
})
</script>


it will returns ReferenceError: route is not defined
But if you change to this:
<script>
import {defineComponent, h, onMounted, ref} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: "MyComponent",
    setup () {
        const myRoute = ref('');
        onMounted(() => {
            myRoute.value = route('sounds.categories')
        })
        return { myRoute }
    },
})
</script>


everything is going to be all right
